# Where to check GET/POST parameters? (MVC)

Tags: php, security, model-view-controller

my website layout:

index.php:
 - front controller
 - include header.php
 - include template.php
 - include footer.php

Front controller checks the URL, and decides which template to include, or if it was an action, do the error checking and forward to the view.
I've got a search form, it posts input data (with GET method). Front controller gets it, calls "action_search.php", halts if there are errors, and then includes the "search_template.php", this shows the result of search. Until now, controller checks the GET parameters (they are exists, escaped etc) and redirect to the view, but what is somebody direct call the view via browser? Script will die "unknown GET parameter" so it must be done again in view. But it hurts MVC. Then how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use mod_rewrite to force everything through your index.php then every request will be processed thru index.php in the way you want, and it can decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your MVC should be setup in a way that does not allow users to access your view directly via the browser. Use .htaccess rewrite rules to redirect all requests to the front controller.

Comment: yea, thanks for the ideas, its already done, I forgot to mention :) but anyway, in the meantime I figured out I used a script as action and view in the same time... I meant, if I do an user adding, it has a "action_useradd.php" action which adds him into the DB and redirect to a view, but it mustn't be allowed right? View cant be called as an action, right?

Comment: another thing, if script cant be called directly, module can. Now: action_doSearch.php -> redirects to "searchList" module if its ok. Site looks like: "www.sitename/searchList?what=sdrsdf&num=424" but if I just call "www.sitename/searchList" then it fails because it wont find the GET parameters

Comment: Yes, a view should not be called as an action. You shouldn't redirect to the view, but rather include it. In your .htaccess file, add a rule that prohibits visiting the view directly.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from "hiding" the pages using mod_rewrite/.htaccess, you can just have php pages that shouldn't be accessed directly in a directory that's not a subfolder of your http document root.

Comment: said in other words, you only need need index.php in your document root and everything else outside, in a directory which is not in the document root. Check Zend Framework default directory tree for examples